# Adobe Air: Can you draw something outside of a window?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, window, draw

For example, how would I draw an image outside of my window area, anywhere on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create a new window inside your application and place it somewhere on the screen. If you set systemChrome to none it will not have any menu bars and will appear if there is nothing on the screen unless you fill it.

See http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=WorkingWithWindows_1.html for more information about windows.

A tutorial to spawn new windows without any menu bars and outlining is here : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/creating_toast-style_windows.html

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to draw outside your window. You can however simulate that effect by creating a maximized transparent window and then drawing on it so that it seems you are drawing at arbitrary points on the screen. You will face issues like the visible windows below the transparent window will be inactive till you minimize the transparent window.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the issues I'll face. Very helpful!